# What is the appropriate forum for technical discussions about Ripple?

Tags: ripple

Is there a mailing list where software developers and other interested parties can have technical discussions about the Ripple source code and other aspects of the network?

Bitcoin Stack Exchange is more suitable for Q&A, where questions have definite answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of forums. Ripple Labs has an [official forum](https://ripple.com/forum/) that the developers read regularly. There's also a [Google Ripple Server group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ripple-server).

Comment: In particular, I'd direct you to the [Developers sub-forum](https://ripple.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2&sid=60430162c99c67c2e77aae320fc22c69) of the official forum for any technical discussions, even if you're not a developer.

Comment: @dchapes Why do you have multiple forums?

Comment: It's a specific part of the same forum, not another forum.

Answer (score 0):

I like http://opencoin.in  This is most active Ripple discussion forum

Answer (score -1):

There is not very active Q&A:

http://www.rippleoverflow.com/

And mostly active ripple chat at freenode:

IRC chat.freenode.net:6667 #ripple